# How to get data from nested json with python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get some data from this api response.
Trying to print the amount of kills but I don't understand how.
Because after "stats" there are a lot of "metadata" keys.

This is the code

```
import requests 
import json
import sys

url = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/1/Edr1X'
headers = {'secret'}
 r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.text)

#Get Kills amount
data = r.text


#load the json to a string
 resp = json.loads(data)

#get the stats
print (resp['data']['stats'])

#get the amount of kills how?
print (resp['data']['stats']['metadata']['kills'])
```

This is the response from print r.text

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "9d0cd2c0-9408-4925-908d-5fcf0dfeb0b9",
        "type": "player",
        "metadata": {
            "statsCategoryOrder": [
                "levels",
                "combat",
                "game",
                "bullets",
                "ekia-enemy-killed-in-action",
                "objective",
                "team-play",
                "extra"
            ],
            "platformId": 1,
            "platformUserHandle": "Edr1X",
            "accountId": "9d0cd2c0-9408-4925-908d-5fcf0dfeb0b9",
            "cacheExpireDate": "11/1/2018 7:21:38 PM"
        },
        "stats": [
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "level",
                    "name": "Level",
                    "categoryKey": "levels",
                    "categoryName": "Levels",
                    "isReversed": false,
                    "iconUrl": "https://cod-cdn.tracker.gg/assets/ranks/rank_13.png"
                },
                "value": 13,
                "percentile": 83,
                "displayValue": "13"
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "KDRatio",
                    "name": "KD Ratio",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 0.78,
                "percentile": 85,
                "displayValue": "0.78",
                "displayRank": ""
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "Kills",
                    "name": "Kills",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 161,
                "percentile": 86,
                "displayValue": "161",
                "displayRank": ""
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "Deaths",
                    "name": "Deaths",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 206,
                "percentile": 83,
                "displayValue": "206",
                "displayRank": ""
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "Assists",
                    "name": "Assists",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 61,
                "percentile": 81,
                "displayValue": "61",
                "displayRank": ""
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "Melee",
                    "name": "Melee",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 4,
                "percentile": 32,
                "displayValue": "4",
                "displayRank": ""
            },
            {
                "metadata": {
                    "key": "Suicides",
                    "name": "Suicides",
                    "categoryKey": "combat",
                    "categoryName": "Combat",
                    "isReversed": false
                },
                "value": 0,
                "displayValue": "0",
                "displayRank": ""
            },       

        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of kills?
Must I iterate over "metadata"? with a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print([metadata['value'] for metadata in resp['data']['stats'] if metadata['metadata']['key'] == 'Kills'])`

Use a list comprehension to go through each metadata to see if its key is `'Kills'`.

Alternatively, if kills is always the same index of the list, you can just request that list location.

Here's the test I wrote to verify your information:

```
def test_get_kills(self):
    import json
    resp = json.loads(resp)
    kills = [metadata['value'] for metadata in resp['data']['stats'] if metadata['metadata']['key'] == 'Kills']
    self.assertEqual(161, next(kills))
```

If list comprehension isn't your thing (it should be), then the equivalent in loops would be:

```
for metadata in resp['data']['stats']:
    if metadata['metadata']['key'] == 'Kills':
        kills = metadata['value']
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getInfo.py", line 28, in <module>
    print([metadata['kills'] for metadata in resp['data']['stats'] if metadata['key'] == 'Kills'])
  File "getInfo.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    print([metadata['kills'] for metadata in resp['data']['stats'] if metadata['key'] == 'Kills'])
KeyError: 'key'

Comment: [161.0] is the output. Could you be kind to explain what you did?

Comment: Nice answer plus 1+

Comment: List comprehension is what you're looking for. Basically what you wanted was the value for a key in a list of dicts. List comprehension allows you to look through each element of the list, in order to create a new one. It also allows conditionals, which is what we needed for finding the correct dict in the list. I'll post an equivalent loop in a sec.

Comment: Updated answer to include a version without list comprehension.

Comment: Wauw man! I understand it now haha. The version without list comprehension is more understandable for me haha but nice answer. Thanks a lot man :D